# 500 Internal Server Error with Freeform

Tags: solspace-freeform

I just started getting an internal server error on a site that has been running fine for weeks.

Now when I try to access a page that has a Freeform form on it, I get a server error & I am also no longer able to login to the control panel at all.

I switched debug to 2 in my config file and this is the error I get:

Error Number: 1205

Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

DELETE FROM `exp_freeform_params` WHERE `entry_date` < 1450727583

Filename: third_party/freeform/models/freeform_model.php

Line Number: 538

What is going on here? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this was just a temporary server issue that worked itself out.